# How create a printable report using html and css with ASP.NET Core?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-core

I want to design a report with HTML and CSS, but I do not know how these forms are designed. Forms such as pay slips that can also be printed. See the pictures I posted below. Please help me. Thank you

[image: image number 1]

[image: image number 2]

Comment: Look up `print css`. You can use CSS to style how the documents looks & behaves in print and let users use system print dialog to print / save the report as PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `colspan` and `rowspan`.Here is a simple demo:

```
    <table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="9">first line</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            4
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            5
        </td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            4
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            5
        </td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            4
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            5
        </td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            4
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            5
        </td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td rowspan="2">8</td>
        <td rowspan="2">9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>

    </tr>
</table>
   

     <style>
            table, th, td {
                border: 1px solid black;
                text-align:center;
            }
        </style>
```

result:
[image]

You can also change width,height,text-align or background for each tr/td.

Answer (score 0):

There are many templates and tutorials you can use on the internet to find the design you are looking for.

The only thing to consider is to use `width:100%` so your forms become fixed well on the page, also use `margin:10px` (10px is example) to make sure your report stays inside your page.